# How to stream a video frame by frame from sys1 to a qt-application on sys2 and display it in real time, on linux

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, gstreamer

I am trying to send .mp4 file from system 1 through UDP socket to Qt app and app will display the that video.
***I have tried qt app which play .mp4 file present in local directory.
***Qt app able to transmit and receive message from local network (c app) through UDP socket.

Comment: Which parts are you aiming to reinvent? GStreamer already has support for decoding frames from files and sending/receiving RT(S)P streams. All that remains is rendering a GStreamer pipeline onto a Qt application, which I'm sure already exists if you look for it.

Comment: could you please share me any reference code link or docs which describes your  reply :"GStreamer already has support for decoding frames from files and sending/receiving RT(S)P streams. All that remains is rendering a GStreamer pipeline onto a Qt application,"in details.                                                                                                         
because i dont have much idea about GStreamer .

Comment: [this was on the first page of search results for "gstreamer rtp example"](https://docs.gstreamer.com/data/doc/gstreamer/head/qt-gstreamer/html/examples_2voip_2main_8cpp-example.html), as well as several other hits on stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks Botje for u r help. first i am trying to implement these pipeline @command line   at server side i.e. one terminal I am running $gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location =/<.mp4 file path>video_test.mp4 ! decodebin ! x264enc ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000   but it showing :"WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "x264enc"
". I have installed all modules for Gstremer like bad,good, ugly but it not showing any result for x264enc.

Comment: @Botje, x264enc error is resolved by installing all GStreamer module in proper order and setting GST_PLUGIN_PATH